# Do the jsprit TSP and VRP solvers allow provided time and distance constraints between points?

Tags: jsprit

Does anyone know if the jsprit solvers use a 'as the crow flies' geometric distance between two points in a route by default? And if so, is it possible to constrain this by providing to jsprit as parameters pre-calculated times/distance between adjacent points, as provided by e.g. a Google Directions calculation?

This is to allow for classic problems such as the true distance between two points could be much further than the straight-line distance if the real world journey was from one side of an estuary without a bridge being available etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default jsprit uses euclidean distances or as you put it 'as the crow fly' distances. If you want to consider your own distance measure, just implement [VehicleRoutingTransportCosts](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/core/problem/cost/VehicleRoutingTransportCosts.java). Assign it when building your vehicle routing problem with [.setRoutingCosts(..)](https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-core/src/main/java/jsprit/core/problem/VehicleRoutingProblem.java#L174). If you have a time and/or distance matrix, you can also use [this](https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/blob/master/jsprit-core/src/main/java/jsprit/core/util/FastVehicleRoutingTransportCostsMatrix.java).